# modal poupop bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Estou a usar um modal do `bootstrap`.

Chamo o modal apos click num `onclick`, esse modal esta numa página a parte acontece é que o botão **close** não me faz nada.

```js
var btAbrir = $("#btAbrir");
var myModal = $("#myModal");

function load(id){
  //$("#contentLoading").load("../temp/tst.php?id="+id +""); 
  myModal.modal('show');
}

function close(){ 
  myModal.modal('hide');
};

btAbrir.on("click", function () {
  load(0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" onclick="close()" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="btAbrir" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Abrir Modal</button>
```

Comment: Você não tem que adicionar um evento `onclick` para o botão **close**?

Comment: ja coloquei mas mesmo assim não fecha

Comment: Poste o botão com o evento, por gentileza.

Comment: tenho esta função para fechar     function close(){
    
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
   
 
};

Comment: botão    <button type="button"  onclick="close()"  class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

Comment: agora esta me a dar este erro Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/

Comment: Edite sua pergunta, e adicione o código nela. Fica mais fácil para os demais analisarem.

Comment: editei a sua pergunta para colocar o cdn do bootstrap, estranho que o botão Close funcionou normalmente.

Comment: Aqui tá funcionando esse código.

Comment: mas usando ficheiros diferentes?

Comment: Num file php web tenho um funçao para carrega o model e ele abre mas a função para fechar nao fuciona. será por estar noutro ficheiro?

Comment: `data-dismiss="modal"` já executa a ação de fechar o modal. Para que colocar um método para fazer a mesma coisa?

Comment: @IvanFerrer tem razão. A tag button do close ficaria <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" class="close">. Lembrando que deve estar dentro da div do modal.